# How to slave the audio clock to the system clock using ALSA?

Tags: linux, audio, clock, alsa, system-clock

I want to

- make the audio clock to be a slave to the system clock or
- use the system clock to drive the audio system instead of the audio clock.

Is this possible with ALSA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"System clock" is not very well defined.

But anyway, ALSA assumes that hardware devices have their own clocks, because that is how the hardware actually works.

There might by systems that derive all clocks from the same clock source, but this is not part of the ALSA API (because there is no hardware where this could be changed on the fly), and the only way to find out is to know the system architecture.